# Упорядоченные, сортированные и неупорядоченные коллекции

Tags: java, коллекции

В Java есть упорядоченные, неупорядоченные и сортированные коллекции. Чем они отличаюся?
Сортированные хранят элементы в порядке возрастания, например `SortedSet`.
Упорядоченные хранят элементы в определенном порядке, не обязательно по возрастанию, например `List`.
Как хранят элементы неупорядоченные коллекции? По сути там ведь тоже есть какой-то порядок, не перемешиваются же они после добавления каждого элемента.

Comment: Именно перемешиваются. Не после каждого добавления - но иногда перемешиваются.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, Интересно, а с какой целью?

Comment: @jisecayeyo, дело не в цели, а в особенностях внутреннего устройства конкретной структуры данных. Хэшмап частично перераспределяет значения в корзинах после увеличения своего размера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В неупорядоченных коллекциях порядок (именно математический порядок) не гарантируется из-за особенностей хранения.

`HashSet`, например, внутри реализован на базе `HashMap`. Как-то обойти его можно (взяв `iterator`), но глубинного смысла порядок обхода нести не будет (т.к. будет зависеть от размера хэшмапа и реализации `Object.hashCode()`).

Неупорядоченные множества в первую очередь нужны для быстрых проверок на вхождение какого-либо объекта в это множество, а не для обхода элементов.