# как конвертировать коллекцию Set в коллекцию Map

Tags: dart

Как конвертировать коллекцию Set в коллекцию Map? В данном примере я конвертировал Set в List, а затем в Map. Но может есть более элегантный способ?

***main.dart***

```
void main() {
 Set ara1 = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'o'};
 Map ara2 = ara1.toList().asMap();

 for(var i in ara2.entries) {
  print('${i.key} : ${i.value}');
 }

 print('');

 ara2.forEach((k, v) {
  print('$k : $v');
 });

 print('\n${ara2.runtimeType}');
}
```

***ответ***

```
0 : H
1 : e
2 : l
3 : o

0 : H
1 : e
2 : l
3 : o

ListMapView<dynamic>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Важно понимать что элементы Set'а могут быть как [неупорядоченными, так и упорядоченными](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.3/dart-core/Set-class.html). Также во втором примере показал как будет более правильнее чем у вас есть сейчас.

```
void main() {
  Set<String> ara1 = <String>{'H', 'e', 'l', 'o'};

  // 1
  Map<int, String> ara2 = <int, String>{
    for (int i = 0; i < ara1.length; i++) i: ara1.elementAt(i)
  };

  ara2.forEach((k, v) {
    print('$k : $v');
  });

  print('');
  
  // 2
  List<String> ara1Temp = ara1.toList();
  Map<int, String> ara3 = <int, String>{
    for (int i = 0; i < ara1Temp.length; i++) i: ara1Temp[i]
  };

  ara3.forEach((k, v) {
    print('$k : $v');
  });
}
```

Comment: Уважаемый MiT, огромное Вам спасибо. Мне не совсем ясно, что значит упор. и не упор. Если сортировки здесь нет, как можно упор. или не упор. коллецию? Или упор. это не есть сортировка? И по моему вариант ara1.toList().asMap(); более элегантен, не так ли?

Comment: @Sergey по поводу [упор. и не упор.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/555544/261617). `asMap` вам даёт `ListMapView` что не совсем является `Map`.

Comment: Уважаемый MiT, теперь ясно, спасибо.

Comment: Уважаемый MiT. Теперь другая неясность. Мой вариант выдает ListMapView<dynamic> это упор или не упор? Ваш вариант выдает _InternalLinkedHashMap<int, String>
  это упор или не упор?

Comment: @Sergey про упор. и не упор. я больше говорил в контексте `Set`, так как по нему мы предполагаем что будем проходится циклом и создавать `Map`.  Но если вас это тоже интересует `the LinkedHashMap iterates in key insertion order`, в [документации](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.2/dart-core/Map-class.html) всегда об этом пишут. А на счёт `ListMapView` понятия не имею...